# Android accessing UI from second thread

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, checkbox

I have hundreds of CheckBox widgets in my layout and now I'm trying to invert each of them, so if it was checked it won't be checked and vice versa. Obviously such heavy work should be done in separate thread, but the problem is that all the work actually happens the UI. Part of the thread code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < list.getChildCount(); ++x)
{
  final WListRowTarget curRow = (WListRowTarget)list.getChildAt(x);
  curRow.post(new Runnable()
  {
    public void run()
    {
      try
      {
        curRow.getCheckBox().setChecked(!curRow.getCheckBox().isChecked());
      }
      catch (Exception e) {}
    }
  });
}
```

The only thing that this thread actually can do is looping through the list and posting the Runnable for every found checkbox. The problem is that all those Runnables arrive in the UI thread almost at the same time, thus they're all executed at once... The application behaves exactly like I would run the above code in the UI thread - everything freezes. A possible solution is sleeping for some miliseconds after each checkbox so the Runnable can be executed and the UI will have time to process the events... but it's more like a hack.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance,
Snowak

Comment: Are you using a listview to display the checkboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've solved the problem myself. The solution is to use Object.wait() and Object.notify() in order to wait for the Object.post() to do the job. This way I don't post more events until the previous one is executed.

The code looks like:

```
synchronized (someObject)
{
  someObject.post(new Runnable()
  {
     // some work here
     synchronized (someObject){ someObject.notify(); }
  });
  someObject.wait(); // this line unlock the object
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> I have hundreds of CheckBox widgets in my layout and now I'm trying to invert each of them, so if it was checked it won't be checked and vice versa. Obviously such heavy work should be done in separate thread

No - this is fundamentally UI work, and frankly setting a bunch of flags *isn't* really "heavy" work. Most of the "work" involved is actually the UI repainting - which obviously *does* have to be done on the UI thread anyway. Creating lots of different tasks to execute on the UI thread is just giving it *more* work to do - just do the whole lot in one batch on the thread without trying to use different threads.

As a separate matter, I wouldn't want to use a UI with several hundred check boxes even on a desktop, let alone on a mobile - are you sure you shouldn't redesign your UI? You may find that coming up with a more elegant design removes any performance hit anyway...

Comment: It's just my custom implementation of list. Android's ListView lack too many features (like the possibility of putting it into ScrollView). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming you are using a listview to display all your checkboxes* you don't need to use multiple threads. Store the state of the checkboxes in a data-structure and process everything  using a single thread.

While doing the processing ( sounds so wrong :-) ) just show a spinner. You can then display all the checkboxes based on the state stored in the datastructure.

Comment: So how are you displaying all the checkboxes?

Comment: They're part simply part of LinearLayout